# PHP delete script, return to 'viewsubjects.php?classroom_id=NO VALUE'

Tags: php, mysql, uri

As the title states... I am deleting a 'subject' from a 'classroom' I view classrooms, then can click on a classroom to view the subject for that classroom. So the link where I am viewing subjects looks like:

```
viewsubjects.php?classroom=23
```

When the user selects the delete button (in a row) to remove a subject from a class, I simply want the user to be redirected back to the list of subjects for the classroom (exactly where they were before!!)

So I though this is simply a case of calling up the classroom ID within my delete script. Here is what I have:

**EDIT:** corrected spelling mistake in code (this was not the problem)

```
    $subject_id = $_GET['subject_id'];
    $classroom_id = $_GET['classroom_id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE subject_id=".$subject_id;
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection)
    or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());


header("Location: viewsubjects.php?classroom_id=".$classroom_id);
exit();
```

The subject is being removed from the DB, but when I am redirected back the URI is displaying with an empty classroom ID like:

> viewsubjects.php?classroom_id=

Is there a way to carry the classroom ID through successfully through the delete script so it can be displayed after, allowing the user to be redirected back to the page? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Delete operation must be performed using only POST method, not GET

Comment: To avoid SQL injections *(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection )*, you should escape your `$subject_id`, or make sure it's an integer ; use, for instance : `"DELETE FROM subjects WHERE subject_id=" . intval($subject_id);`

Comment: I have delete operation using GET on other scripts and it works fine? Or do you mean it in another sense?

Comment: It's dangerous if you use this on the public side, by guessing urls people can delete everything on your site.

Comment: @Derek - I think what Col means is that it will work but for security reasons its better to use POST variables rather than GET variables as users can see these in the URLs and change them and delete other or all records. You could still use GET if you limit who can delete what to a particular user i.e. a logged in user that owns a particular record in your DB.

Comment: @Derek Wait until some smart bot will delete all your database in attemt to just index your site or just prefetch a few pages. If you don't trust me you can refer to RFC2616. Not security, but just meaning of these methods.

Comment: @Derek As for your question, you just failed to show here the html code for the deletion form. Where, I suspect, you failed to pass classroom_id to the deletion script

Comment: Say goodbye to your table...
viewsubjects.php?classroom=23';DROP+TABLE+subjects;

Answer (score 3):

Spelling mistake in your code?

Change line 2 to:
`$classroom_id = $_GET['classroom'];`

Comment: Exactly. 
Free advice: turn on or look at your error log, then you would have noticed the error, because you're reading a non-existing variable.

Comment: this is incorrect as I did not paste the code in, i typed it in the question with error

Comment: That's what you get for not pasting real, tested code ;-) There's nothing wrong with reducing code to the essential parts. But please make sure that the abridged version shows the same behavior and doesn't introduce _new_ errors. It's a waste of time and afford for all of us...

Comment: Your question is incomplete and still not corrected, is it? You call your listing page with ?classroom=23 but, more important, how do you call your delete script? ?classroom=23 or ?classroom_id=23?

Answer (score 2):

It should be  `$classroom_id = $_GET['classroom'];`

Not:  `$classroom_id = $_GET['classrom_id'];`

**EDIT** You have edited your code but does the string in the $_GET variable match that string in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Just to note, if this is an admin function: great.

If this is on the front end, you need to consider making sure the subject_id is clean as it would be very easy to hack into your site.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add classroom_id to the delete form in a hidden field?

Comment: Why put more in the form when you can read it from the database when deleting it anyway?

Expanding your form like this is unnecessary and more work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little verbose ...but let's see what happens with

```
if ( !isset($_GET['subject_id']) ) {
  echo 'DEBUG: missing GET parameter subject_id';
  var_dump($_GET);
  die;
}
if ( !isset($_GET['classrom_id']) ) {
  echo 'DEBUG: missing GET parameter classroom_id';
  var_dump($_GET);
  die;
}
else if ( 0===strlen(trim($_GET['subject_id'])) ) {
  echo 'DEBUG: empty GET parameter subject_id';
  var_dump($_GET);
  die;
}
else if ( 0===strlen(trim($_GET['classrom_id'])) ) {
  echo 'DEBUG: empty GET parameter classroom_id';
  var_dump($_GET);
  die;
}

$subject_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['subject_id'], $connection);

$sql = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE subject_id='$subject_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
if ( 0===mysql_affected_rows($connection) ) {
  echo 'no such subject_id found. no records have been deleted';
  die;
}

header("Location: viewsubjects.php?classroom_id=".urlencode($_GET['classrom_id']));
exit();
```

(it also fixes the sql injection vulnerability)

Answer (score 0):

If response to above, it'd be easier todo:

```
if (!isset($_GET['subject_id']) || empty($_GET['subject_id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['subject_id'])) {
 throw new exception('Subject Id is not set');
}
```